# Currently you have no contract instances to interact with

Tags: remix-ide

I'm trying to write my first smart contract by copying code from a video online. The instructor could "Deploy" but for some reason I'm getting this error message even though the code is exactly the same.
[image]

Comment: You might want to explain your question better in order to get some answers. also sharing code snippets (covering your business logic) always helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have not compiled your contract. You can simply compile by clicking compile button available. Please refer to the image
[Compile button Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M6uq.png).

Comment: Though this suggestion does repeat the advice of another answer, it does also mention the button, which arguably makes it more current and useful.

Answer (score 1):

The area where this message is shown is where deployed contracts are listed. This is simply stating that you haven't yet deployed a contract.

In the contracts drop down, I see you do not have a contract selected. You'll need to select a compiled contract to deploy. If there aren't any, its because you haven't yet compiled one. You'll need to select a .sol file in the compiler panel, and run the compiler. Once complete, you should see the compiled contract in the drop down.

Once you hit deploy, assuming the selected contract deploys successfully, you'll see the contract listed here.

Answer (score 1):

For me simply refreshing the page solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs when you don't compile the code. You need to compile it first and then the deploy button will appear

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm if all else fails, refresh the page. I ran into the same issue  and after refreshing the page everything was working correctly again. It was the first time I had ran into this issue, so I too was a little puzzled. I usually start a new browser session so it was not an issue before.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Remix plugin on VsCode and encounter "Currently you have no contract instances to interact with" problem, correct your solidity version which version you wrote and compile it again.

Answer (score 0):

GO IN THE COMPILER SECTION, THEN ADVANCE SETTINGS AND SIMPLY CHANGE THE EVM VERSION TO THE VERSION YOU ARE USING.

Answer (score -1):

Refreshing solves the issue after you have compiled.